# How do I find the optimal function input integer (X) to get closest to a target output (Y)?

Tags: java, python, excel, pseudocode, vba

This answer relates to an excel macro in VBA and I am looking for the optimal solution. The answer can be provided in Pseudo Code, Python, Java or Excel compatible VBA. The approach should be able to written in Excel VBA.

If you have alternative solution (Ie functional programming in Haskell) I would like to see that too, but that is not the primary concern.

I have a complicated function: y = function (x) where x is the input and y the output.
x is an integer
y is a double (can contain decimals)

I know the target range that x must be in, lets say 0 to 2000, or 800 to 1800.
**I also know what y should be.**

***function*** is a computationally expensive function and should be calculated as few times as possible.

I cannot see the contents of ***function*** or it is too complex to analyse.
The output of the function is an increasing curve.
ie. x=2 > x=1 then y(2) > y(1)

I **need to find** the x value that gives me a y value closest to the known value of y.

What is the most computationally efficient way of doing this?

---

I thought of dividing the range in 20 regions and looping through. The loop will stop at the first y larger than the target. ie. it will run between 2 and 20 times. Then I would go to the precise unit (integer) and loop through this sub-region or sub-range, which would mean a maximum number of calls being (startingrange /20 - ie. if starting range was 0 to 600), then the function would be called between 2 and 30 times.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps recursively.
I seem to be missing the boat here?

Comment: what? ....  I feel like we are missing a critical peice of information

Comment: so you get `x = some_range_min_and_max` and `y=some_target_value` and `fn=some_expensive_calculation` ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley there is no information missing. Is there anything I need to clear up

Comment: Half the search space for `x` with each function call, i.e. use bisection search. It won't get more efficient than that as far as I understand your specs.

Comment: @JoranBeasley lets take the simplest case and say the function mutiplies `x` by 2, then `y = function(x)`, 4 = f(2)... So lets say we had to find what x would give y target=4, how could we do this efficiently in the generic case.

Comment: Binary search would probably be good here, requiring only log2(600) function calls, or approximately 10.

Comment: ahh ok I think i understand now ... binary search is indeed the path you need for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function whose y value always increases, you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to quickly narrow down the range of potential values. Sample Python implementation:

```
def binary_search(func, min_x, max_x, target_y):
    while max_x - min_x > 1:
        midpoint = (min_x + max_x) / 2
        if func(midpoint) > target_y:
            max_x = midpoint
        else:
            min_x = midpoint
    return min_x

print binary_search(lambda n: n**2, 0, 600, 300**2)
```

This algorithm has logarithmic efficiency. For a range of 0 to 600, it calls `func` only ten times; and only eleven times for a range twice as large.

Comment: Wow I was writing the same binary search function but without your speed and precision :) (speed and precision in writing python I mean)

Comment: lol just saw this as I posted the same approach in java! Guess OP will have their pick of languages by the end of this. +1 for concise neat code.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously with a normal function the answer would be to perform algebraic operations until you can solve for `x` (since if you know `y` there is only one variable). However, operation on the assumption that the function cannot be analyzed, the best way to find something in a range is a binary search. This will run the function O(log(n)) times, which is likely going to be the fewest you can achieve with these conditions.

Something like this.

```
find_x(int xmin, int xmax, double y){
    if (xmin == xmax){
        return xmin;
    }
    int xmid = (xmax-xmin)/2;
    int resx = func(xmid);

    if (resx <= y){
       return find_x(xmin, xmid, y);
    if (resx > y){
       return find_x(xmid, xmax, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a second, simpler function that evaluates the difference between the desired value y and the output of *function*, then evaluate a new x as a proportion of the difference. For example, in Python

```
while abs(y-desired) > *whatever accuracy you need*:
   y = function(x)
   x = x + (x*((desired - y)/desired))
return x
```

By finding (desired - y), you find how far off the answer was, as well as making the change positive if y is too small or negative if y is too big. This difference is divided by desired to make the difference a percent error. Finally, the percent is multiplied by x to make the percent error into a change proportional to the range of x, whatever that may be.

The formula may need to be changed slightly based on the specifics of your case, but I think this should help you get a more accurate answer with many fewer runs through the big function.

Comment: This is a good approach for linear functions, but for a curve as stated in the question the value of x will flip way above then way below, never getting any closer.

Comment: I didn't catch that, thanks. I wonder if there's a way to account for that using possibly a root or a log? In any case, the binary searches above ought to be satisfactory for this.