# How to find the lowest integer value of an input X for an output Y using a Python search function

Tags: python-2.7

I am querying an API with an input value of `x` and it returns an output value of `y`. The relationship between `x` and `y` is non-linear and the magnitude of `x` can vary depending on which segment `s` and group `z` is being queried. For example:

```
query = https://www.ip_address.com/?segment=s&group=z&input=x

returns:
    {'output':y}

where:
    x = integer
    y = integer
    s = string
    z = string
```

The python query function would look like this:

```
def call_api(segment, group, input):
    url = "https://www.ip_address.com/?segment={0}&group={1}&input={2}" .format(segment, group, input)
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content
```

Some typical values for different groups are:

```
For Z=A & S=Banana
X       Y
10      4501
100     4235
1000    1213
2000    785
3000    518

For Z=B & S=Banana
X       Y
10      2589
100     1869
1000    389
2000    201
3000    118

For Z=C & S=Banana
X       Y
10      4251
100     3952
1000    2346
2000    1785
3000    1396
```

I'm looking for a python function that will quickly find the lowest value of `x` for a target value of `y`, `s` and `z` (without trying all possibilities to limit the number of API calls). For example: What input value `x` is required to get an output `y=1314` when `s=Banana & z=A`?

Note: Values of `x` which are close together (e.g., 2541, 2542, 2543) may have the same value of `y`, but not always. When this happens the search function should keep going until the lowest value of `x` is found.

This answer to a similar question seems to indicate that I will need a binary search function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659051/2039864

However, I'm unable to work out how to integrate it with my `call_api` function, especially as my value of `y` reduces, not increases.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my problem with the following modification to the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659051/2039864:

```
def binary_search(func, segment, group, min_x, max_x, target_y):
    while max_x - min_x > 1:
        midpoint = (min_x + max_x) / 2
        if func(segment, group, midpoint) < target_y:
            max_x = midpoint
        else:
            min_x = midpoint
    return min_x
```